# Are there any hormones that are only present in children and not adults?

Tags: endocrinology

I am trying to ascertain whether or not there are hormones only evident in children which then desist with growth & age.

I have found nothing of any use from google, wondered if perhaps here would fetch better results.

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably not. If so, I'm sure it would be easy to find them because of the number of people obsessed with longevity. Typically adult humans will have the same hormones as they were when children, but maybe at a lower intensity since they're past the growth stage. Unless perhaps castration happens. Ouch.